# NancyFx Testing returning invalid Json

Tags: c#, json, nancy

We are using NancyFx for hosting a single page application and multiple ReST endpoints. The code and the test use the same bootstrapper, the only difference being that in the tests we are using the Nancy Browser from the test framework.

If I return a simple object from the website everything works as expected wither via the application or the test framework. However the real problem is that the object we are returning contains some dynamic data, although it is not a dynamic object itself. The application works fine but the tests fail because the JSON is invalid, strings are missing quotes and dates are formatted incorrectly.

```cs
var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);
_response = browser.Get("http://localhost/...", with =>
{
    with.HttpRequest();
    with.Header("Accept", "application/json");
});

var bstr = _response.Body.AsString();
```

I have attached a method to the pipeline AfterRequest method whilst testing and I can see the JSON string looks good by looking at the Response property on the NancyContext but as soon as we get the response object back from the browser and convert it to a string it is no longer valid JSON.

```cs
protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
{
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
    pipelines.AfterRequest += Foo;
}

private void Foo(NancyContext obj)
{
    //Can see the Response on the NancyContext here
}
```

If I cannot solve this I will look at ditching the Nancy testing framework and just self host in the context of the tests.

**EDIT**

I get a similar result using NancySelfHost. It looks like it is not picking up the Json.Net serializer when using self host or the test browser. I was using the standard setup of registering a Custom serializer in Tiny IoC https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet.

```cs
public class CustomJsonSerializer : JsonSerializer
{
    public CustomJsonSerializer()
    {
        this.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        this.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }
}

public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

        container.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), typeof(CustomJsonSerializer));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working but the solution feels wrong.

This was done by removing the Json.Net custom serializer and wire up from the bootstrapper.

```cs
container.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), typeof(CustomJsonSerializer));
```

And adding the JsonNetSerializer manually to the internal configuration.

```cs
protected override NancyInternalConfiguration InternalConfiguration
{
    get
    {
        return NancyInternalConfiguration
              .WithOverrides(nic =>
              {
                  ...
                  nic.Serializers.Clear();
                  nic.Serializers.Insert(0, typeof(JsonNetSerializer));
              });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with ObjectId structures (MongoDB), which were serialized to JSON without quotes. 
Try to change default Nancy serializer to Json.NET:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet

It solved this problem for me.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the first part of the question but in the edit I mention that this is what we were doing however the Json.Net serializer was not being picked up when using either the self host or the Nancy test browser. Only when being hosted through Asp.Net. I do have a work around which I am going to post as an answer.

Comment: weird - I checked it now in self host and it's working fine with Json.NET serializer from nuget.